# OpenTelemetry Observabilty

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am using OpenTelemetry to get logs/traces/metrics from my application (.net SDK). What will happen if the collector is not installed/run?

Is the data stored anywhere (memory)? Does it affect my app’s performance (increasing memory/CPU/other impact)?

I couldn’t find any documentation for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the OpenTelemetry SDKs there is a buffer of the data before it leaves the application, this will retry, but not for long. If your destination for the telemetry from your application (in this case the collector) isn't running, you will see increased memory usage, however, that will only affect the inline performance of your application in the same way as excessive memory usage would. This is because the sending of the telemetry is done async, so it's not done on the same thread as the one serving the users. Async isn't true for all SDKs, but the .NET one is that way.

Comment: Can it be configurable? (the size of the buffer) in order to minimized the impact of memory?

Comment: where can I read about it?

Comment: You'd need to consult the docs for your specific language/framework. https://opentelemetry.io/docs is a good place to start.